# How to track file change

Tags: process, solaris, trace

`nsswitch.conf` file always corrupts somehow. I do restore from my backup every time it corrupt.
When this file corrupts, its time stamp is changing. Now I wonder if there is a way to track that file ? I'd like to know which process or maybe user cause that corruption. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Have you considered involving `inotify`? See the questions tagged [tag:inotify] (or better [search for them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=inotify)).

Comment: As I see Solaris does not support inotify.

Comment: @mibzer - It would probably be a good idea to mention your operating system in your question in future.

Comment: It seems you have a bigger problem than tracking changes: You might want to investigate why your file gets corrupted in the first place.

Comment: can you provide an example of the 'corruption'?  is the file truncated, filled with garbage, emptied, etc?

Comment: @Tim Kennedy well it was returning to a binary file rather than a normal data file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either [set up auditing](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=647) or use [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace). There are various examples how to use it to monitor file access on the interwebs, for example [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/dtrace-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg01493.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you are running Solaris 11, then NWAM builds the /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/nsswitch.conf files are controlled by NWAM.  The entries you need should be configured via svccfg commands, then when the network services start/restart, the files will be "created" based on the svccfg settings.